# How to extract string from regex in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I would like to do something like that:

```
(def my_regex #"[1-9]")
(extract-string my-regex)
=> "[1-9]"
```

Is it possible in clojure?

Comment: why is this on hold? op posted expected results and most likely there are no attempted solutions, that's why he asked here in the first place. Do you want to say OP should have found the `str` solution by intuition? Even Beschastny didn't know it and recommended use of .toString first. The Q clearly demonstrates an understanding of the problem being solved as OPs code clearly hints at the fact that a function like `extract-string` should exist that returns the expected result. OP expects the desired result to be extractable from the regex object. What more do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy:

```
(.toString my_regex)
```

Actually, all `Java` (and `Clojure`) objects have [`.toString` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returning its string representation.

There is also a [`str` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/str) in Clojure, which calls `.toString` on each of its arguments and concatenates results:

```
 (str my_regex)
```

So, it's doing the same thing, but it's pure Clojure.